# ¿Cómo acceder a un fichero en java y mostrarlo?

Tags: java

Tengo que acceder a un fichero creado por mi y mostrar sus datos. El código que he hecho es el siguiente: ¿Alguien me da una pista de por dónde seguir? He creado las corrientes de entrada y salida y el ArrayList pero no se continuar.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,    

IOException {
    int opcion,edad;
    String nombre;
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("seleccione opcion");
    System.out.println("1: Escribir nombre y edad de una persona");
    System.out.println("2: Leer y mostrar los datos");
    opcion=entrada.nextInt();
    if (opcion==1){
        System.out.println("Escriba el nombre");
        nombre=entrada.next();
        System.out.println("Escriba edad");
        edad=entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Datos guardados correctamente");

    }
    else if(opcion==2){
        System.out.println("Leyendo y mostrando los datos almacenados");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("opcion no valida");
    }
    String f = null;

    ArrayList<Persona> Personas = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
    FileOutputStream FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
    OutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream ObjectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);}
    catch (IOException ex) {
                    }
    try{
    FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(f);
    ObjectInputStream ObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fis);}
    catch (IOException ex) {
                    }   
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo tú pregunta quieres escribir y leer datos desde un fichero que contiene 'la información' de *n* 'objetos'.
Para esto, y es importante, esos objetos a guardar deben de implementar la clase `Serializable` [[API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)]

Para serializar en Java es muy sencillo y vas en buen camino, te dejo unos métodos sencillos.

**Serializar (Escribir)**

```
public <T extends Object> void write(final T data, final String fileName) throws IOException {
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName)));
    oos.writeObject(data);
    oos.close();
    oos = null;
}
```

**Deserializar (Leer)** *(ACTUALIZADO: gracias a [Luiggi Mendoza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/227/luiggi-mendoza))*

```
public <T extends Object> T read(final String fileName, final Class<T> clazz) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)));
    final T data = clazz.cast(ois.readObject());
    ois.close();
    ois = null;
    return data;
}
```

Sí solamente querías leer y escribir ficheros cualquiera aquí mis apuntes: [ENLACE](https://github.com/ticdenis/NOTES_Ticdenis/tree/master/Java/Files_and_I:O)

---

Debes de crear e inicializar antes la Lista (`ArrayList`), solicitar los datos en un bucle y almacenarlos en la lista, para agregar (meter, poner, añadir) se utiliza el método `add(Object)` de `ArrayList` y para obtener el método `get(int)`. Aquí un ejemplo para guiarte:

```
List<Persona> listaPersonas = new ArrayList<>();
// Solicitas datos en bucle y al final del bucle...
listaPersonas.add(new Persona(nombre, edad);
// Mostrar datos de la lista...
for (int i = 0; i < listaPersonas.size(); i++) {
    System.out.printf("[Persona] Nombre: %s Edad %d",
    listaPersonas.get(i).getNombre(), listaPersonas.get(i).getEdad());
}
// Serializar datos (Escribir --> Guardar)
write(listaPersonas,"listaPersonas.dat");
// Deserializar datos (Leer --> Obtener)
List<Persona> p = read("listaPersonas.dat", listaPersonas.getClass()); // Ojo el directorio donde está.
```

Comment: En el método read por lo menos deberías tener como argumento `Class<T> clazz` para usar `clazz.cast` y no ese casteo inseguro de (T)

Comment: Revisando el código que está en tu enlace a github, tengo algunos comentarios: 1) Una interfaz no debe tener campos porque ellos son constantes, es decir son variables `public static final` y veo que tienes instancias de ellos en la interfaz `FileManager` de manera que tu interfaz se amarra a un solo archivo para trabajar cuando debe ser flexible. 2) utilizas el patrón singleton en Las clases `Read` y `Serialize` cuando evidentemente ess clases son Utilitarios, lo mejor es quitar esa instancia de singleton que complica el diseño y volver todos esos métodos estáticos

Comment: 3) si no quieres que el cliente no pueda crear instancias de estas clases utilitarias lo mejor sería declarar un constructor privado y que no reciba argumentos, asimismo los métodos de las clases utilitarias deben ser auto suficientes y no utilizar campos estáticos de la clase utilitaria a menos que esos campos sean constantes

Comment: Tienes razón, voy a realizar los cambios. Pero una pregunta, ¿porque es inseguro el casteo de T en el método read?

Comment: El casteo a genéricos de la manera en que está en tu código es inseguro porque en tiempo de ejecución se borra la información de genéricos así que tu código luce así: `(Object) variable` lo cual no tiene mucho sentido. En cambio `Class<?>` te hará el casteo de una manera más segura puesto que estás utilizando reflexión (reflection) y usas el verdadero tipo de clase al que necesitas castear

Comment: Muchas gracias,con lo que me has dicho lo he conseguido ;)

Comment: Yo no utilizaría genéricos para algo tan simple, ya que es programación avanzada. Y puede confundir  más aún, en vez de contribuir. Saludos